How can I prevent muffled audio?
I am making an assistant in Python using SpeechRecognition and some other libraries. I use this library for both getting the voice and turning it into text.
But when I try to listen to some audio, while the program is recording me, the audio is muffled. I know this is happening when getting audio from a microphone in general, from discord to google audio search, but is there a way to stop the audio from getting muffled at least in the detecting a wake word part?
I have tried to search, but it led to nothing. Here are a few searches that I have tried:

voice muffled when microphone is working

voice muffled when microphone is working voice recognition python


Here is the code that I have tried (referring GeeksForGeeks voice assistant using python):
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
from ecapture import ecapture as ec
from urllib.request import urlopen

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def takeCommand():
    
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...") 
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 
        print("Unable to Recognize your voice.") 
        return "None"
    
    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
  clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    
  clear()
    
  while True:
    query = takeCommand().lower()
        
    if 'open google' in query:
      speak("Here you go to Google\n")
      webbrowser.open("google.com")

    elif 'open youtube' in query:
      speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
      webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

    elif 'open stackoverflow' in query or 'open stack overflow' in query or 'open stock overflow' in query:
      speak("Here you go to Stack Over flow. Happy coding")
      webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com") 

    elif 'open youtube' in query:
      speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
      webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
      
    elif 'open duck duck go' in query or 'open duckduckgo' in query:
      speak("Here you go to Duck Duck Go\n")
      webbrowser.open("https://duckduckgo.com/?t=vivaldi")
      
    elif 'close' in query or 'exit' in query:
      speak('Goodbye')
      break
        
    elif 'wikipedia' in query:
      try:
        speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 3)
        speak("According to Wikipedia")
        print(results)
        speak(results)
      except:
        print('Could not serch Wikipedia')
        speak('Could not serch Wikipedia')
    
    elif 'the time' in query:
      strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("% H:% M:%S")
      speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")

